# Variable seen as undefined when it has value in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, setinterval, two-way-binding

I'm making a simple countdown on click with two-way binding in Angular. I have a number element which gets its value in a function with setInterval which executes on button click. But when I launch it the value is seen as undefined and after a second the value is shown but the undefined remains.

HTML component:

```
<p class="alert">{{comUser}} {{visibleCounter}}</p>
<button class="buttonMain" (click)="log(email, password)" (click)="countTo0()">Login</button>
```

COMPONENT.ts

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
public comUser = '' }

  public visibleCounter;
  public counter: number = 4;
  public alert: string = "SIGN IN";

  countTo0() {
  const frequency = setInterval(() => {
    this.visibleCounter = this.counter;
    console.log(this.counter);
    let oneDown = this.counter--
    console.log("visible counter: ", this.visibleCounter);
    if (this.counter <= 0 ) {
      clearInterval(frequency);
      this.document.location.reload()
    }
  }, 1000);
  }
```

and then the function is called in else statement as this is part of login component. If you pass wrong credentials, you get a message that says it will reload in [number of seconds].

```
else{
        this.comUser = `Reloading in ${this.visibleCounter}`;
        this.alert = "WRONG LOGIN OR PASSWORD"
      }
```

And the result looks like this (the counter works, but the "undefined" remains)

[image]

Thanks for any hints on what may be the cause of this weird behaviour.

Comment: Stackblitz Please.

Comment: Hi Vikas, it has already been solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify things, just get rid of the `comUser` prop altogether. What's happening is it gets computed once (I'm assuming, if the credential check failed in the fragment you actually skipped) when `visibleCounter` is not yet defined. And you don't need it anyway. Just have in the template

```
<p class="alert">Reloading in {{ visibleCounter }}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

*visibleCounter* is displayed twice in your template :

- with *comUser*
- with *visibleCounter*

You should remove it from comUser : as *visibleCounter* is only initialized after 1 second with *setInterval*, it's still undefined when comUser is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `` this.comUser = `Reloading in ${this.visibleCounter}`; `` is running when `visibleCounter` is still undefined and it will not run again while the template is shown.

So basically this happens:

```
this.comUser = `Reloading in ${undefined}`
```

`this.comUser` will have this value: `"Reloading in undefined"`

Then in the angular template you append again `visibleCounter` like this:

`<p class="alert">{{comUser}} {{visibleCounter}}</p>`

The rendered result will be (if visibleCounter is 4):

`<p class="alert">Reloading in undefined 4</p>`

I think the solution is to just remove `${this.visibleCounter}` from
this line

`` this.comUser = `Reloading in ${this.visibleCounter}`; ``

Actually you do not have to define `comUser` in the Class if you just want to display it in the template. Just write the value directly into the template.